# Fastest way to get data from big textfiles

Tags: php, performance, bigdata

I'm downloading some files that are each 100mb big and zipped as .gz. When I'm unzipping them they have a size of 350 mb.

In this file, there are some identifieres at the beginning for the language, like `en` for English and `de` for German.

Next to it there are some numbers I need to save. An example for a row in this file looks like this

`de Gemeinschaft_nicht-anerkannter_Staaten 1 10446`

As I said the file is really big, and I have multiple of them (in total about 1tb of data in multiple files and 300mb per file)

Now, I'm doing the following:

1. Since there are also other languages, I'm first getting only the ones that begin with `de`.

`preg_match_all('#^(de\s+.*)#m', file_get_contents('tmpfile.txt'), $matches);`

Then I'm getting the `name` which is the second column in a line, which would be

`Gemeinschaft_nicht-anerkannter_Staaten` in our example.

Now, I'm looking if there exists a database entry for that particular name and the current date. If there isn't one, I save it to the database, else, I "udpate" it, by increasing a specific number. However, I'm on this since 11 am this morning and have "only" 21,572 entries yet, and am nowhere near the end. It could take weeks to get all the data. Is there a faster way, than doing it like I'm doing it? Here's the code I'm using.

Note that as I said, I'm downloading one file per hour since the 1st may, which means I have 24 files with 100mb each (300mb unzipped) for about 120 days (4 months) which make it 2,880 files I have to go through.

```
<?php
// some requires

// some settings
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit',-1);

// some information about the url and file type
$baseUrl        = 'http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/';
$baseName       = 'pagecounts-';
$fileName       = '.gz';

// i want to get a file for every hour since the 1st May
$begin      = new DateTime('2014-05-01 00:00:00');
$end        = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H');
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

iterating through every hour
foreach ($dateRange as $date){
    /**
     * @var DateTime $date
     */

     // building the download url
    $url            = $baseUrl . $date->format('Y') . '/' . $date->format('Y-m') . '/' . $baseName . $date->format('Ymd-H0000') . $fileName;
    print 'Now doing file: ' . $url . '<br>';
    // downloading the file
    file_put_contents("tmpfile.gz", fopen($url , 'r'));
    // unzipping
    unzipfile('tmpfile.gz');
    // getting only german articles
    preg_match_all('#^(de\s+.*)#m', file_get_contents('tmpfile.txt'), $matches);
    $matches = $matches[0];
    foreach ($matches as $match){
        // getting the informations
        $info = explode(' ', $match);

        //check if already exists in database
        $pageStatistic  = new Pagestatistic();
        $state          = $pageStatistic->loadFrom([
            'articleName'       => urldecode($info[1]),
            'articleLanguage'   => 'de',
            'pageViewsDate'     => $date->format('Y-m-d')
        ]);

        if ($state){
            $pageStatistic->articlePageViews = $pageStatistic->articlePageViews + $info[2];
        } else {
            $pageStatistic->articleName         = urldecode($info[1]);
            $pageStatistic->articleLanguage     = 'de';
            $pageStatistic->articlePageViews    = $info[2];
            $pageStatistic->pageViewsDate       = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        }
        // save/update
        $pageStatistic->save();
    }
}

//method to unzip files
function unzipfile($fileName){
    $buffer_size = 4096;
    $out_file_name = str_replace('.gz', '.txt', $fileName);
    $file = gzopen($fileName, 'rb');
    $out_file = fopen($out_file_name, 'wb');
    while(!gzeof($file)) {
        fwrite($out_file, gzread($file, $buffer_size));
    }
    fclose($out_file);
    gzclose($file);
}
```

Comment: Seems that extracting data from textfiles is fine. It's your database activity that is the bottleneck here. The general advice is to try doing things in batches, this significantly increases throughput.

Comment: Regular expression on a 350MB file? Good luck! Why not read line by line and do your logic on only one line at a time? Instead of regular expression, you could explode on spaces and check if the first part is `de`, etc.

Comment: Don't use `file_get_contents` as it loads all your data into the memory, that is 350mb of ram only to load the file. Next you preg match the file contents, again, a high memory usage thing you're doing. Instead, use fopen to get a handle to the file and read the file line by line and apply the regex only for that line. You can use `strpos()` to find the language, that is instead of using a regex since strpos is faster.

Comment: kingkero - The regular expression is "pretty fast". Takes less than 1 seconds to get all the results. It's the db inserting that takes much time

@SergioTulentsev are you talking about something like a multi query instead of doing one query for every match?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answeres, and I will "fix" the problems with the regex and the downloads, but the problem would still remain, since it's the inserting that takes time, the regex takes less than 1 second.

Could a multi_query solve the problem?

Comment: if you are that concerned about the queries performance, tune your server accordingly for high inserts. Also, try inserting in batches, or write them in file and then call something like `exec('mysql -u USER -pPASS DATABASE < file.sql 2>&1 &');` to insert them in background and much faster than your current solution.

Comment: Is there a strict requirement that PHP must be used? If not, you could write a simple Map Reduce job for this task.

Comment: Mostly because I have to check if an entry for the article and the date already exists. If it does I have to add a value instead of inserting it, any ideas?